# R how to rotate and place x axis labels in spineplot?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble rotating and placing x axis labels on a spineplot in R. The dataset I'm plotting has several levels of Categories with longer names

dataset for replicaiton here:

```
psdat <- data.frame(Cat = rep(paste0('LongcategoryName',1:5),(1:5)*5), Level= rep(c('Low', 'Med' , 'High'), 25))
```

I'm after a spineplot ....

```
spineplot(Level~ Cat, data=psdat)
```

but the labels are too wide for the plot so I would like to rotate them....

This seems to work OK, but I have to eyeball and guess the levels for at and cant seem to get them in the same way that you would with barplot.

```
spineplot(Level~ Cat, xaxlabels=F, data=psdat, xlab='')
at <- c(0.04, 0.15, 0.3, 0.6,0.9)
axis(1, at=at, labels=levels(psdat$Cat), las=2)
```

can anyone help with how to get the at values? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `par(las = 2)` before you create the plot:

```
psdat <- data.frame(Cat   = rep(paste0('LongcategoryName', 1:5),(1:5) * 5), 
                    Level = rep(c('Low', 'Med' , 'High'), 25))
par(las = 2, cex.axis = 0.75, mar = c(7, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
spineplot(Level ~ Cat, data = psdat, xaxlabels = levels(psdat$Cat), xlab = '')
```

[image]

---

You could also use line breaks (`\n`) inside the labels. For example, if your category names contain spaces, then just replace them with `\n`:

```
psdat <- data.frame(Cat   = rep(paste0('Longcategory Name', 1:5), (1:5) * 5), 
                    Level = rep(c('Low', 'Med' , 'High'), 25))
par(las = 2, cex.axis = 0.75, mar = c(7, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
spineplot(Level ~ Cat, data = psdat, xlab = '',
          xaxlabels = gsub(levels(psdat$Cat), pattern = ' ', replacement = '\n'))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: @knussear since you are new to SO:  you might want to mark this question as answered (marker at the top left of the answer that fits you best).

Comment: Done Thanks @martin-schmelzer